# How to solve a linear equation 'mx - ny = 0' with two unknowns such that I get strictly integer solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem Statement**
I have a linear equation of the form $m*x - n*y = 0$, where $m, n$ are known rational numbers (integers, terminating decimals, and repeating decimals). How to find the values of $x, y$ that solves the above equation such that they are strictly integers.

**Research Effort**
If $m = 10, n = 2$, then it is very easy to find $x, y$ whose values will be 1 & 5 respectively. But I don't know how to solve this equation for large numbers, fractional numbers. I used matlab to write a small code to find this using trial & error

```
length = 100;  
m = 1440;  
n = 115.2;  
x = 1:1:length;
mx = m*x;
y = mx/n;
```

Then i look through y array to find the first integer number & that becomes my solution. But how do i do solve it mathematically without this matlab trial & error

Comment: Multiply by the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of the denominators of $\,m,n\,$ and you get an equation in integers. Then it's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question at the very beginning of Linear Algebra. Several cases have to be considered. 1) $n=0$ and $m=0$. Then the equation is satisfied for *all* $x,y$.
2) If $n\not=0$ you may choose $x$ arbitrarily and calculate $y$ from the equation as $y=\frac{mx} n$.

The remaining case *$n=0$ and $m\not=0$* is treated similarily.

**Edit** according to modified question: We may assume that both $m$ and $n$ are integer s by multiplying the the equation with some suitable integer.
Then in the first case above $x,y$ are arbitrary integers. In the second case $x$ is arbitrary up to the  condition that $n$ must be a divisor of $mx$. The Thier case again is of a similar taste.

It seems that the added condition makes the question one belonging to the theory of numbers. A tag would be *linear congruences*.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the detail that x & y solution have to be an integer only.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer but as mentioned in my OP, *m, n* are rational numbers. They can be integers or fractions. Also, I could not find the *linear-congruences* tag &  I can't create new tags

Comment: If $m,n$ are rational, there are  integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $m=a/b,n=c/d$ (and $b,d\not=0$). Then you may multiply the original equation with $bd$ to get the equation $(mab)x-(nab)y=0$ with *integer coefficients* $mab$ and $nab$. Another tag would be diophantine equation. You also may look at Wikipedia, or so, with both tags.